# Making a Custom Post Type Publish Loop

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, plugin-development, wp-query

I want to re-publish all previously published products of a custom post type. Let's say the post type is "events"

This is what I was thinking something like this:

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'events',
'post_status' => 'publish', // get only published posts?
'posts_per_page' => -1
);
$posts = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $posts -> have_posts() ) {
while ( $posts -> have_posts() ) {
     wp_publish_post(NEED TO GET ID)
}
}           
wp_reset_query();
```

The thing I can't figure out how to get the id in the loop or how to get just published posts (took an educated guesss)

**Edited **

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'events',
'post_status' => 'publish', // get only published posts?
'posts_per_page' => -1
);
$posts = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $posts->have_posts() ) {
while ( $posts->have_posts() ) {
    $posts->the_post();
    wp_publish_post($post->ID)
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ( $posts->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $posts->have_posts() ) {
        $posts->the_post();
        wp_publish_post($post->ID)
    }
}
```

That should do it. You need the call to [`the_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Methods) to walk through the post set properly. It also sets up the `$post` object.

That should set all of the posts to 'publish', which is what [`wp_publish_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_publish_post) does. I guess I am not sure what you mean by "re-publish". Possibly you mean "alter the publication date". To do that you need to use [`wp_update_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post) and change the `post_date` and `post_date_gmt`.

```
if ( $posts->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $posts->have_posts() ) {
        $posts->the_post();
        wp_update_post(array('ID'=>$post->ID,'post_date'=>'','post_date_gmt'=>''))
    }
}
```

Setting the dates to nothing will cause it to default to "now"-- just tested that.

If you are trying to get these to show up again in a news feed, that still won't do it. You have to edit the `guid` for that but [doing so is highly discouraged.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL#Important_GUID_Note)

Also, I'd recommend you name your variable something other than `$posts`. WordPress uses that name. You are clobbering the default variable.

Comment: so the code now looks like revised post above?

Comment: I am not sure what your comment means.

Comment: I revised the code in my original post (see the bottom of it). I am wondering if thats now the correct code?

Comment: Well, does it work? Does it do what you want?